# How to insert data to Kentico Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

Excuse me I have a problem with Connecting Kentico Database I want to insert data to Kentico Database. What api for do it ? and how to i do it ? . Give a Doccument[link] or sample code for me please .

i will try to use api ITableManager,DatabaseHelper,ITableManager Properties. but i don't know about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert Data to Kentico Database by User Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249251/insert-data-to-kentico-database-by-user-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, you haven't shown any effort trying to resolve your issue. Please read the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com) first.
Plus, there are [API Examples](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/API+examples) directly in the Kentico UI which you can have a look at. They demonstrate the basic (CRUD) operations with objects and documents.

Basically, to work with documents use [DocumentHelper / TreeProvider](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Working+with+pages+in+the+API) (`DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(...)`). To work with other objects use *InfoProvider (e.g. `UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(...)`).